# How to alter the name of a key in each dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have the following list of dictionaries, `my_list`:

```py
[
{'nsme':'bob',
 'age':37,
},
{'nsme':'amy',
 'age':40,
},
{'nsme':'pat',
 'age':28,
}
]
```

How can I create a new list that corrects the spelling of `'name'`? I figured out how to do it for any single dict in `my_list`:

```py
{'name' if k == 'nsme' else k:v for k,v in my_list[0].items()}
```

But when I try to loop through the items in `my_list`:

```py
[{'name' if k == 'nsme' else k:v for k,v in my_list[i].items()} for i in my_list]
```

or

```py
{'name' if k == 'nsme' else k:v for k,v in my_list[i].items() for i in my_list}
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

For context, I ran a pretty lengthy process to scrape a lot of data but accidentally had a typo in naming the `'name'` key. Rather than fixing this and rescraping everything again, I figured it'd be a lot easier to just create a new list that fixes the typo.

Comment: Neither example you provided produces an error you say it does.

Answer (score 2):

`i` refers to a dictionary in the list, *not* an index. So, your dictionary comprehension should be:

```py
[{'name' if k == 'nsme' else k:v for k,v in elem.items()} for elem in my_list]
```

(I've renamed `i` renamed to `elem` in this code snippet for clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```py
[{'name' if key == 'nsme' else key: value for key, value in d.items()} for d in my_list]
```

When looping over a list of dictionaries the elements you get returned are dictionaries, not indices of a list. Hence the error that the list indices need to be integers or slices, not a dicationary.